# Use EF Seed to insert Chinese Content, show garbage code in database

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I use Seed method to insert some sample content to database. It works well for English content, however it generated garbage content in database when I try input Chinese content.

```
       context.Questions.AddOrUpdate(i => i.Content,
            new Question
            {
                Content = "我们知道：太阳的温度很高",
                QuestionType = "Simple",
                Source = "网站",
                UpdateTime = DateTime.Parse("2016-3-13")
            },
```

I tried to context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlCommand), however it still failed.

```
String sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO Question (Content,QuestionType, Source,UpdateTime) VALUES(N'我们知道：太阳的温度很高', 'Simple', , N'网站', '2012-06-18 12:00:00')";
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqlCommand);
```

Any ideas?
Thanks a lot in advance :-)

Comment: check column type into database. should be nvarchar or nchar

Comment: Can you please confirm on what @JahirulIslamBhuiyan is asking you to check. Please capture the sql query that EF is firing onto the database using SQL profiler tool. Also please tell us out of the four column that is shown in the code snippet which column is primary key?

Comment: I compared profile input through Web interface which the Chinese content works fine.

Comment: Input from Web interface the SQL Profile shows: exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[Question]([Content], [QuestionType], [QuestionLevel], [Source], [UpdateTime], [Answer])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5)
SELECT [ID]
FROM [dbo].[Question]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [ID] = scope_identity()',N'@0 nvarchar(2000),@1 int,@2 int,@3 nvarchar(max) ,@4 datetime2(7),@5 nvarchar(2000)',@0=N'应用题',@1=1,@2=2,@3=N'自己想的',@4='2016-05-06 00:00:00',@5=N'999'

Comment: If I use update-database which trigger the Seed function, the profile looks like "INSERT INTO Question (Content,QuestionType,QuestionLevel, Source,UpdateTime) VALUES(N'ÎÒÃÇÖªµÀ£ºÌ«ÑôµÄÎÂ¶ÈºÜ¸ß',0,1, N'ÍøÕ¾','2016-03-13 12:30:00') . The Chinese Content already be wrong

Answer (score 0):

This is determined by the collation of database for table 'Question'.
When you create a new database, choose the Collation value to be a Chinese one (e.g. Chinese_PRC_90_CS_AS). But I am not sure why there are so many options and the meaning of these options.

Comment: When I input from ASP.NET MVC web interface, the Chinese content works fine. So it does not look not only caused by Collation.